# Terminating Django Channels function

Tags: python, django, sockets, django-channels

I currently have a website, where when the user clicks a button, it sends a socket which then runs a web scraping program and returns the results to the user as it goes along.

For the sake of simplicity, lets say that upon receiving a socket, it gets routed to consumers.py which has the following code:

```
def ws_message(message):
    while True:
        print("5")
        time.sleep(5)
```

However, I also want to add a "terminate" button to stop this function from running but am not sure how to go about doing so.
I've thought about doing the following:

```
cont = True
def ws_message(message):
    text = message.content['text']
    if text == 'terminate':
        cont = False
    if text == 'restart':
        cont = True
    while cont:
        print("5")
        time.sleep(5)
```

However at the same time this code doesn't seem particularly elegant, and so I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do so.

Comment: Care to explain why the time sleep ?

Comment: It's just an example of a long running process